# EmailMessage class in google app engine python not working?

Tags: python, django, email, google-app-engine, attachment

Is the google app engine document not updated?

It works fine (send email with attachment), when I do this:

```
message = mail.EmailMessage( sender=EMAIL_SENDER, 
subject=subject,body=theBody,to=['test@gmail.com'],attachments=[(attachname, 
new_blob.archivoBlob)])
message.send()
```

But When I use message.attach , it says `EmailMessage` object has no attribute `attach`

```
message.attach("certificate.pdf", new_file, "application/pdf")
or
message.Attachment("certificate.pdf", new_file, "application/pdf")
```

both says :`EmailMessage` object has no attribute `attach/attachment`

In the documentation there are examples of "[Attachment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.mail#google.appengine.api.mail.EmailMessage)".

Please help!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see in the docs, there's class [`google.appengine.api.mail.Attachment`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/mail#Attachment), but class [`google.appengine.api.mail.EmailMessage`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/mail#EmailMessage) does not have any method `attach()`.

Class [`google.appengine.api.mail.EmailMessage`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/mail#EmailMessage) does have an `attachment` property, and that's why it works when you initialize the email with `attachments=[(foo,bar),(foo,bar)]`. You're actually creating new instances of [`google.appengine.api.mail.Attachment`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/mail#Attachment) (using the tuples as [explained in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.mail#google.appengine.api.mail.Attachment)), adding them to an array, and using this array as the `attachments` property when initializing the email.

Notice that in the docs, when they write `attachment = mail.Attachment('foo.jpg', 'data')`, that `mail` is a reference to the imported `google.appengine.api.mail`, and not an instantiated mail object.

Getting back to your example (please note that I'm not a python dev and I have not tried it, I'm just looking through the docs and making assumptions), instead of

```
message.attach("certificate.pdf", new_file, "application/pdf")
```

you should probably go more on the way of

```
attachment1 = mail.Attachment("certificate.pdf", new_file, "application/pdf")
attachment2 = mail.Attachment("another_certificate.pdf", new_file, "application/pdf")
message.attachments = [attachment1, attachment2]
```

It's been years since I played with python, but feel free to explore this ideas and edit my answer in case I got anything wrong (or post your own answer).

Comment: thanks for details , spent a decent amount of time trying to figure this out your answer is actually correct but i still couldn't get it working for some reason. I fixed it using the send_mail function(added below as my answer)

Answer (score 1):

The attributes of the EmailMessage class are assigned dynamically, like this<sup>*</sup>:

```
class EmailMessage(_EmailMessageBase):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for name, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)
```

Therefore, if `attachments` isn't passed to the constructor as a keyword argument, the instance has no `attachments` attribute, and you get an `AttributeError` if you try to reference it.

As Jofre observes in their answer, you can still assign to `attachments` directly:

```
message.attachments = [attachment1]
```

after the attachments attribute has been created, you can also append to it:

```
message.attachments.append(attachment2)
```

<sup>*</sup> This is a simplified version; in the real class the assignment is done in a separate method, but in essentially the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with send_mail function , one of the mistakes was not specifying ".pdf" for the file name instead I was only naming it "certificate"

Also If you have speficied any handlers in app.yaml for direct url access, make sure "application_readable" is set to true so that the file is accessible within the application:

```
- url: /certificate.((pdf)|(PDF))
  static_files: pages/pdf/certificate.PDF
  upload: pages/pdf/certificate.PDF
  application_readable: true

 additional_pdf = open(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../pages/pdf/certificate.pdf').read()

 mail.send_mail(sender=EMAIL_SENDER,
                  to=['mmyemail@gmail.com'],
                  subject=subject,
                  body=theBody,
                  attachments=[(attachname, blob.archivoBlob),("certificate.pdf",additional_pdf)])
```